# Font Awesome Shortcut

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, oocss

I am using Awesome Font in my web project. Is there any option how to make shortcut to bunch of icons? E.g. I have [`circle-thin`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/circle-thin/) icon. Now on page I want to put three icons together so the result is `OOO`, but I do not want to put 3x times `<i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>` s in the code. So can I somehow create CSS shortcut when I write it, 3 circles will appear?

Example:

```
.circle-three {
<i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
}
```

Then on page I would use only `.circle_three` class instead of typing the code for circle three times.

Comment: Purely with css and html not without a lot of copy-pasting css-code i guess. Maybe take a loot at [less](http://lesscss.org/). Then you take the less-files FontAwesome provides and you should maybe be able to something like. `.circle-three:before { content: @fa-var-circle-thin~@fa-var-circle-thin~@fa-var-circle-thin }`

Comment: What language/framework are you developing your site in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [CSS file](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css) included with Font Awesome, you'll find this rule:

```
.fa-circle-thin:before {
  content: "\f1db";
}
```

So, you can make a similar rule to achieve what you want:

```
.fa-circle-three:before {
  content: "\f1db \f1db \f1db";
}
```

[Check this pen for an working example.](http://codepen.io/rscafi/pen/GJRdzv)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible by both

- adding a new class and creating a rule that inherits everything and only adds the changes you want to, and
- by creating a brand new class that will substitute the original one completely.

Since the only attribute in the [FontAwesome CSS](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css) for `fa-circle-thin` is the `content` of the *before* pseudo-element, and hence there is nothing else to inherit, in this case both solutions (appended class or new class ) have the same behavior / meaning.

```css
.fa-circle-thin.triple::before {
    content: "\f1db\f1db\f1db";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
Standard : <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
Triple   : <i class="fa fa-circle-thin triple"></i>
```